# on a family of inner products generating the usual Schwartz topology

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

I'm currently reading some features about the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and I found on a paper of J.E.Roberts that the Schwartz topology on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ i.e. the one generated by the family of inner products $$
||f||_{m,n}:=\sup_{\mathbb{R}}\left\lvert x^mf^{(n)}(x)\right\rvert ;\;\;m,n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
can be seen as generated by the following family of inner products $$
\langle f,g\rangle_n=\int (1+|x|)^n\sum_{|k|\leq n}f^{k}(x)g^{k}(x)dx.
$$
Any explanation why this holds (or some references where can i find one) would be greatly appreciated.